# How can I verify the certificates when connecting to an FTP server with Filezilla?

Tags: tls, certificates, ftp

Today most hosting providers start a TLS connection whenever you connect to their FTP server. But Filezilla doesn't store any root certificates, so whenever you connect to an FTP server and the TLS connection is started, you get this message:

> The server's certificate is unknown. Please carefully examine the certificate to make sure the server can be trusted.

Then there are some details about the certificate: fingerprint, subject, issuer, etc. It is also possible to see the details of the other certificates in the chain, up to the root certificate. I don't see any way to download the whole certificates though, but I might be wrong. Filezilla just asks me: "trust this certificate and carry on connecting?" So I'd like to know what I should do to make sure I can trust it.

Here are the screenshots for more information. Under those windows the only buttons are "ok" or "cancel" (not included in the screenshots). Note the first is "certificate in chain #0", then there's #1 and #2. From what I understand, in this example the root certificate should be "AddTrust External CA Root".

[image: first certificate]
[image: second certificate]
[image: third certificate]

Answer (score 3):

FileZilla ***never automatically trusts certificates.***

You mention a chain of trust, but not much about the root certificate. Does it seem like one that should be trusted? You could compare the fingerprint of the provided root certificate to one in the certificate trust store on your local machine. This would emulate the basic/default behavior for most TLS clients, to trust the client because you trust the CA.

To be particularly fastidious you could contact the owner of the FTP server and ask what the **fingerprint** of their certificate is. When connecting, if the presented certificate has the correct fingerprint and you trust it, your future connections will henceforth be secure from MITM attacks.

Supposing the FTP owner is not particularly helpful, another way to increase trust would be to observe the certificate fingerprint over an extended period of time using several different internet connections and devices. If you only ever see a single key fingerprint it would indicate that either nobody is attempting an MITM attack or that they are successfully doing so every time you connect. Supposing you are an optimist, trust the key with this fingerprint.

Comment: I actually don't know what Filezilla does exactly, only what I see. It shows me a chain of certificates, and I suppose they are all provided by the FTP server I'm connecting to. But I don't know if Filezilla is actually verifying that chain. Also, I'm afraid the actual root certificate isn't included, because the last certificate up the chain has a root CA as the issuer, but the subject of the certificate is different, so I guess that is not the actual root certificate, and I can't compare it to one I already have and trust (I tried, fingerprints differ).

Comment: @reed can you add a screenshot of the certificate trust chain to your question?

Comment: Ok, I added the screenshots of the window that appears in FileZilla.

Comment: @reed Is the sha1 fingerprint of certificate #2 `afe5d244a8d1194230ff479fe2f897bbcd7a8cb4` ?

Comment: No, I don't see that string anywhere. How did you come up with that?

Comment: @reed That fingerprint is for an identically named certificate that is in the Windows trust store, which is apparently not the same certificate... After looking at the screenshot I did a bit of research and find that TLS certificate verification support in FileZilla is **awful**. It does not verify the CN from the certificate at all. Here it is showing a chain of intermediate certificates that would be sent by the server *but it does not seem to actually check it against a client side trusted certificate*.

Comment: @reed My suggestions at this point would be either of these options: 1) Connect using a client with good TLS certificate verification support, record the fingerprint and trust that certificate in FileZilla. 2) Use the technique in the last paragraph of my answer to observe the certificate with index 0, trust it when you feel comfortable.

Comment: You gave me an idea: the ftp domain in the example is also accessible via HTTPS (as you can see the certificate is signed by cPanel). I used the browser to load that domain and checked the details of the certificate: the fingerprints match! So I can trust the FTP certificate because it's the same that the browser accepts. It's a cumbersome method, but in many cases it's likely to work if the same certificate is used for HTTPS. Otherwise I don't know if there's a better alternative than FileZilla (on Linux), I thought that was the best available.

Comment: @reed If you trust the certificate in the browser it is reasonable to trust it in FileZilla, it is a good strategy. Poor support for pki does not mean FileZilla is bad, and in fact it is actually one of the better graphical clients. It just does a bad job helping you use CA signed certificates to trust a server. Now that you have trusted that certificate, it should otherwise be safe. The situation with SSH is not better, there literally is no pki. I would be surprised if the command line ftp client even supports tls.

Comment: @reed In this form post, the author of FileZilla (botg) discusses certificate support very briefly. It seems to not be a major priority. Describing your problem as a feature request there might actually help them prioritize this feature. https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=40417